# Como utilizar OAuth2 para validar usuarios en un API REST hecho en PHP

Tags: rest, oauth, oauth2

Me gustaria saber ya que hice un API REST en PHP y solo me falta la parte del login, he escuchado de OAuth2 pero en realidad no se como utilizarlo o implementarlo en PHP para que cada vez que haga una peticion me valide dicho usuario

Comment: Usaras el consumo desde donde ?

Comment: Si buscas una implementación completa de un servidor OAuth 2.0 puedes fijarte en https://jmouriz.github.io/authentificallizer/. Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Como detalle, comentarte que por definición una api test no debería utilizar validación tipo oauth2. Esto es debido a que no debe guardar estados, y al utilizar oauth2 estás "guardando" el estado de un usuario.  Deberías utilizar jwt para asegurar tu api.